# How can I have multiple view on my android application?

Tags: android

How can I have multiple view on my android application. I have this question for one of my school hw!

Comment: You write a program (in Java, preferrably!) that puts the views on the screen.

Comment: there is `ViewGroup` ..which has a `ViewGroup.addView(multipleView1)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve and what have you tried so far? Without that we can only guess, which is not gonna help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use weights and relative layouts in your XML file associate with that activity!